# How to format powershell output in Logic App

Tags: azure-logic-apps, azure-powershell

I am trying to fetch expiry date of all the webhooks using an runbook and then sending that output in an email using logic app.

Below is the script to get webhook expiration date which will be stored in an hashtable

Powershell Script

[image]

This is the powershell output on the screen

Powershell Output

[image]

But this is the format in whic i am getting the email

Email Notification

[image]

Can anyone explain how to get email notification in table format ?

I am using get job output connector to get the runbook output and i select (Content) to get the output from previous step

Logic App Email Connector

[image]

Comment: You’ll need to break it up and create a HTML table.

Comment: Can you show me how its done ?

Comment: Can you provide the PowerShell text output in a code block in your question? Makes it easier to help.

Answer (score 0):

You are receiving this because the output from runbooks is read in a paragraph tag inside the mail connector. After reproducing from my end, I could get the answer using`pre` tag which defines preformatted text. Alternatively, you can send the output as attachment to the mail which gives you output in the required format. Below is the flow of my logic app.

[image]

Results in mail:

[image]